# How to download canvas image(base64) in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas. Chrome downloads the image but other browser
don't download the image.

This is the code:

```
html2canvas($("body")[0], {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.download = "test.png";
      link.href = img;
      link.click();
        }
    });
```

How can I get the image to download on other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

`download` attribute is not wide compatible.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

However, it works in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Android, if doesn't work for you it's probably because the user doesn't make a click event (you are attempting to download on rendered event), so Chrome  have a security bug.

If user doesn't make click in nowhere, no clicks will be triggered due security reasons. Obvious.

Comment: What should I do instead of click event ??

Comment: Make a button, when user clicks in that button you are able to let download the file. Not on rendered event.

Comment: Hmm almost correct (for the browser support part at least). For the user click part, every browser which does support the `download` attribute, (*in their current version, can't remember early implementations*) i.e Chrome, FF, and Edge, do trigger the download of the file on js `AnchorElement.click()` method. Only FF has one more *security* step, requiring the anchor to be appended to the document for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if I add the `link` into the page before trigger `click` as below,

```js
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
```